# Implementing ajax functionality using Mysqli And PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

How can I use ajax php and mysqli to read data from my database
without using any button? 
When I add a row to the table, I want information to be appear on page without loading/refreshing the page or click a button. Can I do that?

And this information will be appear like the code below

**php code**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = intval($_GET['id']);
  $date = date("l jS \of F Y");
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from tbl_dailyprogress where db_activityid='$id' and db_d='1'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
  if ($count != 0) {
    echo"<table class='ol-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf table-bordered' id='alternatecolor'>";
      echo"<thead class='cf'>";
      echo"<tr>";
      echo" <th  style='background:#f7ac01;font-size:16px;vertical-align: middle;text-align:center'rowspan='2'  >Date</th>
              <th style='background:#f7ac01;font-size:16px;vertical-align: middle;text-align:center'rowspan='2' >Notes</th>        
              <th style='background:#f7ac01;font-size:16px;vertical-align: middle;text-align:center'rowspan='2' >Progress %</th>
          ";
      echo"</tr></thead><tbody>";
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $idp = $row['db_id'];
        $date = $row['db_date'];
        $note = $row['db_note'];
        $progress = $row['db_progress'];
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td data-title='Date'>";
        echo $date;
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td data-title='Note'>";
        echo $note;
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td data-title='Progress %'>";
        echo'
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:' . $progress . '%">
            ' . $progress . '%
          </div>
      </div>';
        echo"</td>";
      }
      echo"</tr></tbody>";
    echo"</table>";
    echo"<br/>";
  }?>
```

Comment: use jQuery with Ajax

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  You want rows added automatically when a user adds a row? if the user adds a row in the browser, why would you need to query the DB for more rows? You already have the new row in the browser.

Comment: how can i do that i don't have experience with that if you can aid me plz

Comment: If you want it without refreshing the page than you have to make a ajax call to render the table.

Comment: Do you have any controller in your website ?
You mean when you insert something in your db to make a request and display inserted data?

Comment: no i have a form i update some info and in the same page i print for user updated info but it's not appear directly i need to refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example, lest assume that you what to load you data in container div tag `<div id="container"></div>` from page my_data.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").load("my_data.php");
});
```

Comment: please in page my_data.php how to put my php code to work correct

Comment: I dint get you what you say... Only you need to specify URL which you what to access .

Answer (score 0):

In theory it is not possible to catch the event happens in server side.

In practice it is done by sending request to server and getting response.

All you need is just send some request using ajax periodically. If there is new information in database ajax will return it to client. Then you can process it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are inexperienced, I would suggest you to please go through the w3schools Ajax PHP tutorial first...There you will understand how to implementation ajax functionality and also, you will understand what Ajax can do and what Ajax can not...